# React: How can I get a count up to load only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small account balance component that counts up the current balance of a user
using react-countup.

[image]

This component is used on multiple pages, and I want the component to conduct the count-up only once, on the first time it is loaded. While the documentation and functionalities are extensive, I've been struggling to find a functionality such as 'Load Once' in the documentation.

*How can I limit the load up to the very first time it's triggered?*

```
<h1 className="text-3xl mb-5 md:mb-0 lg:-mb-0 2xl:mb-0 text-white">
            <CountUp duration={2.75}  separator="." start={0.00} end={29348.92}/></h1>
            </div>
            <h1 className="ml-2 text-white">CHF</h1>
```

Comment: Do props change?

Comment: It's likely re-rendering, based on how the page is changing - in which case there's not enough context in your question to work out why that is. What is the component that it is inside doing for example?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want the count-up animation to run only once?

Comment: @Pwnedev: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Medi: no, the props don't change.

Comment: And did you code the CountUp component? If so, can you also share the code to that?

Comment: @Pwnedev - no, as mentioned above it's 'react-countup' https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup

Comment: @DennoFreezy you're right, didn't see it mb. My tip is to instead of starting the Counter like that just use the manual method. "Manually start with render prop" section shows the code you need to use. Make an invisible div or something else that you can use an "onClick" method that calls "start". Then you can control whenever the action is triggered by making a ref to that div and call his onClickk method. I would use "useEffect" to call it when the page is first loaded

Comment: @Pwnedev - your comment solved the problem: can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting the Counter like that just use the manual method.

[Manually start with render prop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup#manually-start-with-render-prop) section shows the code you need to use.

Make an invisible div or something else that you can use an "onClick" method that calls "start". Then you can control whenever the action is triggered by making a ref to that div and call his onClick method.

I would use "useEffect" to call it when the page is first loaded

Answer (score 1):

If it's changing while you're on the page it's most likely rerendering in which case you should use the useEffect hook to control it.

If you want it to count up the first time and then stop counting up when you reload the page you can use localStorage to know save that it has been counted up and then when you reload the page you can check inside the localStorage to see if you should count it up again or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more detailled what the use of localStorage would look like for this element?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense for you to use localStorage for this. Eitherways to use "useEffect" to control it you must do what I wrote in the last comment

Comment: As @Pwndev said there's a better way to do this with the Countup component props and useEffect. But if you really want to do it with localStorage you can just set call localStorage.setItem('CountedUp', true); And then check localStorage at a page realod with useEffect, if localStorage is empty it should count up, if it's not then it shouldn't.